# How can I justify paragraph text in Corel Draw and make the bottom line aligned right (not left)?

Tags: text, alignment, corel-draw, paragraph

It seems that Corel Draw just fully ignores this variant having these justification options:

- None
- Left
- Right
- Center
- **Full Justify**
- Force Justify

**Full Justify** could have had the desired option of Left or Right bottom line alignment, but I don't find it anywhere.

Does Corel really align the bottom line only to the left?

Comment: I think full justify right doesn't exist on Corel Draw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible in a paragraph text nither artistic text.

If I had limited number of paragraphs I would take my chances inserting a tab.
If the paragraph uses a period at the end, I would use a decimal tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the Paragraph text to artistic text then it is possible...

Comment: And that means? How to do that? Please explain better! Usually a one-line-answer is not good ...

Answer (score 0):

Step #1:
Select the Paragraph text
Step #2:
Press Ctrl+F8 or Right click and select "Convert to Artistic Text"
Step #3:
Now change the Alignment style to Full Justify

Comment: Yes, I knew about **full justify** (i've wrote about it initially). But this option makes, I guess, only the left-alignment for a bottom line of text.

Answer (score -2):

Simply follow these steps:

1. press force justify after selecting the paragraph
2. come on to the last line and press SPACE bar till you shift the entire last line to the corner.

Comment: that is not a proper way to align text